# What kinds of formatting can be used in custom flag text?

Tags: support, flags, markdown

I've noticed that custom flags can have some markdown in them.  For example:

> [image: Flag text: See the <code>></code> at the end? It's a link. This might or might not be spam, but it is odd...]

What exact subset of markdown is allowed there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's comment "mini-Markdown", documented here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting. Note that shorthand links ([help], [so], [beer.se], etc.) are not currently rendered.

Comment: Are shorthand links the ones like `[link text](http://example.com)`, `[link text][1](newline)[1]: http://example.com` or just `http://example.com`?

Comment: Shorthand links are predefined symbols you put between square brackets that expand into full links. For instance, `[help]` -> [help], `[beer.se]` -> [beer.se].

Comment: Is there a list someplace of the strings that make up shorthand links? Didn't know those existed!

Comment: In fact there is, @sphanley. I may even have linked directly to it in the answer below which we are now conversing!

Comment: Oh, hah! Foolishly hadn't clicked the link since I was skimming on mobile. Thanks!