# How Do You Use Comment Shorthand Links?

Tags: support, comments

Apparently, I'm missing something.

According to the docs, there are [comment shorthand links](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). In theory, you type something short into an SO comment, and it expands into something else.

One of those cited links is `[mvce]`. I tried typing `[mvce]` into an SO comment. I submitted the comment, and the output had the literal text `[mvce]`, without any sort of expansion into what is described ("link to [/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with the link text "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example".").

I also tried making it the target of my own Markdown link (e.g., `[This is the link text][mvce]`), with no effect (the output was the same as the input).

According to [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275647/115145), these things do not render. In that case, what is the point of having them, if they will not do anything?

So, how is this feature supposed to work? And, any chance that the docs could be updated to explain how to use these comment shorthand links, beyond just listing them?

Comment: You've got the "v" and the "c" backwards. Try `[mcve]` instead. (I don't think that particular one works on Meta, as a heads up.)

Comment: Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example.  Not Minimum Verifiable Complete Example.  :)

Comment: @Kendra: Ah, many thanks. I see it working now. My apologies for adding to Meta noise.

Comment: It's not at all noise- I'm sure there are others who have had similar issues. Never hurts to ask for clarification.

Comment: I heard the sound of your head slamming into the desk all the way down here in SC.  You okay?

Comment: @Will: Sorry, I can't hear you, over the sound of my head slamming into my desk. BTW, ow.

Comment: Wasn't there a feature request to make [mvce] point to the same thing as [mcve]? I used to do that all the time. It helps to remember that the two words related to how much the example should contain go together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's address the points of your question here one at a time.

> One of those cited links is `[mvce]`. I tried typing `[mvce]` into an SO comment. I submitted the comment, and the output had the literal text `[mvce]`, without any sort of expansion into what is described ("link to [/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with the link text "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example".")

So... Your issue here is a typo. The link is `[mcve]`. Note that the "v" and the "c" are swapped in what you typed. This is actually a common typo, given the footnote on the bottom of that page.

> I also tried making it the target of my own Markdown link (e.g., [This is the link text][mvce]), with no effect (the output was the same as the input).

That just flat doesn't work. There have been feature requests to use the magic links with your own custom link text, but so far they have not been implemented.

> According to [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275647/115145), these things do not render. In that case, what is the point of having them, if they will not do anything?

That answer is about formatting in *flag text.* These links are not supported in custom moderator flags, but *work fine* in comments. (Minus a couple exceptions<sup>*</sup>, such as `[meta]` not working *on* a Meta site, or on a site that doesn't have a meta.)

> So, how is this feature supposed to work?

You write a comment with the magic link in it. For example:

> Looks like you're new to Stack Overflow. Your question could use some editing, to make it on-topic and give you a better chance at receiving a good answer.   Why don't you check out the [ask] page for tips? Then, consider [edit]ing your question to help clarify it.

---

<sub>* See [Add data.SE style “magic links” to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000)</sub>

Comment: From my example: "Looks like you're new to Stack Overflow. Your question could use some editing, to make it on-topic and give you a better chance at receiving a good answer. Why don't you check out the [ask] page for tips? Then, consider [edit]ing your question to help clarify it."

Comment: For the final link in your answer, there is actually a [help center page about it](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: I actually had looked at that multiple times... And somehow still managed to overlook it points out the exact exceptions there as well. Thanks. :)